# how to use anti_join for many variables at the same time?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to remove some values of n variables contained in data1 (blood) from data2 (outlier).

```
new <- anti_join(blood1, outlier)
```

I am using `anti_join`, without the "by" option...the result is:  "Joining, by = c("DIM", "PCV", "GLUOX", "COLEST", "UREA", "ca", "P", "Mg", "Na", "K", "Cl", "Zn", "ceruloplasmina", "albunine", "globuline", "GOT", "GGT", "bilirubina", "ALP", "aptoglobina", "NEFA", "BHB", "creatinina", "Paraox", "ROMt", "SHp", "FRAP", "MPO", "AOPP_C")"...but is not correct, `anti_join` keeps all the values of the data1.

Data1

```
DIM PCV GLUOX 
23  14  0.23  
24  15  0.15
28  14  0.01
132  35  0.02
128 12  0.14
```

Data2

```
DIM PCV GLUOX 
128 35  0.14
132 NA  0.23 
NA  NA  0.15
```

My expected output is:

```
DIM PCV GLUOX 
23  14  NA  
24  15  NA
28  14  0.01
NA  NA  0.02
NA  12  NA
```

Comment: Do you want to `anti_join` only by specific columns then? Can you create a small reproducible example and show the expected output based on that?

Comment: @Ronak Shah for all columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` here to replace the `df2` values present in `df1`  with `NA`.

```
df1[] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x %in% y, NA), df1, df2)
df1

#  DIM PCV GLUOX
#1  23  14    NA
#2  24  15    NA
#3  28  14  0.01
#4  NA  NA  0.02
#5  NA  12    NA
```

OR if you need a `tidyverse` solution we can use `map2_df` with same logic.

```
purrr::map2_df(df1, df2, ~replace(.x, .x %in% .y, NA))
```